# Sum from backtrackable predicates or facts

Tags: prolog

I am trying to add different values together, let's say I have this:

```
%fact(Type, Name, Weight).
fact(fruit, apple, 10).
fact(fruit, pear, 20).
fact(vegetable, tomato, 15).
```

Now, the problem I have is if I want to add the weight together from all the fruits. What I have done so far:

```
printWeight(Type):-
    fact(Type,_,R),
    (Type = 'fruit'
    -> true
    ; false
    ),
    *Here I want to add the weight of all the fruits, in case Type = fruit*
```

Anyone got any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I assume that in your first code fragment, you mean to write `% fact(Type, Name, Weight).`I.e. that the first line is a **comment** describing the `fact/3` predicate?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your prolog implementation's documentation for the built-in predicate `bagof/3`, and a more or less standard library predicate that sums numbers in a list (in SWI-Prolog, available as `sumlist/2`):

```
?- bagof(W, Name^fact(fruit, Name, W), Ws), sumlist(Ws, Sum).
Ws = [10, 20],
Sum = 30.

?- bagof(W, Name^fact(meat, Name, W), Ws), sumlist(Ws, Sum).
false.
```

The second query fails, since there are no meat products in your database. You can either leave it as it is (since maybe you want to know if there are no products of a certain type), or use `findall/3`:

```
?- findall(W, fact(meat, _, W), Ws), sumlist(Ws, Sum).
Ws = [],
Sum = 0.
```

If you use SWI-Prolog, there is also `library(aggregate)`:

```
?- aggregate(sum(W), Name^fact(fruit, Name, W), W_sum).
W_sum = 30.
```

You can use `aggregate_all/3` for behavior as `findall/3` above:

```
?- aggregate(sum(W), Name^fact(meat, Name, W), W_sum).
false.

?- aggregate_all(sum(W), Name^fact(meat, Name, W), W_sum).
W_sum = 0.
```

If you don't want to use `sumlist/2` (or are not allowed to), this is how you add two numbers (integers or floats):

```
Sum is A + B
```

So you would have to figure out how to "fold" a list.

**EDIT:**

So, to make a *predicate* `type_totalweight/2`, using for example `findall/3`:

```
type_totalweight(Type, Weight) :-
    findall(W, fact(Type, _, W), Ws),
    sumlist(Ws, Weight).
```

Comment: As the `bagof/3` (and `setof/3`) fail instead of returning an empty list when the goal argument have no solutions, you can improve your answer by (also) presenting and explaining the alternative of using `findall/3`. Also mentioning that `sumlist/2` is usually a library predicate, which may or may not be available depending on the Prolog system would be a good idea.

Comment: @PauloMoura This is a question of "what do I want my predicate to mean", I guess. But a very valid comment anyway.

Comment: Thanks. `findall/3` is also usually easy for beginners as it doesn't require them to understand the concept of existentially-quantified variables used in `bagof/3` (and `setof/3`).

Comment: @PauloMoura Judging by my experience, you are correct about `findall/3` being easier to grasp for a beginner. It comes before `bagof/3` and `setof/3` in terms of cognitive load and if I understand correctly, age?

Comment: Can't I, as I wrote in my code, just increase the weight until the value becomes false?

Comment: @Fjodor You could, but that's not as trivial. `findall/3`, `bagof/3`, and `setof/3` are standard Prolog predicates that have existed since the eighties.

Comment: Okay, but is there a way for me to use setof inside my code. Because I simply supposed to call the function.

Comment: @Boris The oldest manual I have is the "DECsystem-10 PROLOG USER'S MANUAL", dated from November 10, 1982. It describes both `bagof/3` and `setof/3`but no mention of `findall/3`.

Comment: @Fjodor See the edit. Note that it is not a function, but a predicate.

Comment: In any case, an appropriate `setof/3` would be preferable

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use `findall/3` to get all the weights, then use `sumlist` or some other simple function to sum all the weights:

```
findall(W, fact(Type, _, W), L),
sumlist(L, Weight).
```

And `Weight` will hold the sum of the weights. Example of usage:

```
?- Type = fruit, findall(W, fact(Type, _, W), L), sumlist(L, Weight).
Type = fruit,
L = [10, 20],
Weight = 30.
```